# Interchange between expected value and infinite summation (Fubini theorem)

Tags: probability-theory, independence, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ (where the $X_i$ are i.i.d.) and let N be a positive, integer valued r.v., independent from the sequence $X_n$.
Suppose also that $E[N]<\infty$ and $E[|X_i|]<\infty$.

What I want to prove is the following step:
$$E\biggr[\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n\mathbf1_{(N=n)}\biggl] =\sum_{n=0}^\infty E[S_n\mathbf1_{(N=n)}]$$
The explanation should be the Fubini theorem, but for applied it, I should demonstrate that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty E[|S_n\mathbf1_{(N=n)}|]<\infty $$
This is what I have to prove right?

using independence and the fact that the $X_i$ are independent I come up with: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mu nP(N=n)$ where $\mu=E(X_i)$ that we know to be $<\infty$. But here I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Are the $X_i$ non-negative? Are they identically distributed?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta no, they could also be negative.

Comment: If they were non-negative, you could have done a shortcut using monotone convergence theorem. Now, you can also apply dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that all $X_i$'s are independent and have identic distribution.

In order to apply Fubini, you have to show (like you said)

$$\sum_n E(|S_n|I_{\{N=n\}}) <\infty$$

We now prove this:

$$\sum_n E(|S_n|I_{\{N=n\}}) = \sum_n E\left(\left|\sum_{k=1}^n X_k\right|I_{\{N=n\}}\right) \leq \sum_n E\left(\sum_{k=1}^n |X_k|I_{\{N=n\}}\right)$$

$$= \sum_n \sum_{k=1}^n E(|X_k|)P(N=n) = \sum_n n E(|X_1|)P(N=n) $$

$$= E(|X_1|) \sum_n nP(N=n) = E(|X_1|) E(N) < \infty$$

You can also apply dominated convergence theorem:

$$E\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_nI_{\{N=n\}}\right]= E\left[\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^k S_nI_{\{N=n\}}\right] = \lim_{k \to \infty} E\left[\sum_{n=0}^k S_nI_{\{N=n\}}\right]$$$$= \sum_{n=0}^\infty E[S_n]P(N=n) = E[X_1]E[N]$$

here the sequence of functions $(\sum_{n=0}^k S_n I_{\{N=n\}})_{k=1}^\infty$ is dominated by the integrable function $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |S_n| I_{\{N=n\}}$ as the calculation above shows.

Comment: how could I apply the triangle inequality? $\sum_n E(|S_n|I_{N=n})$ $\ge$ $\sum_n | E(S_n I_{N=n}) |$ $\ge$ $|\sum_n E(S_n|I_{N=n})|$ . therefore the sign of the inequality is the opposite of the desired

Comment: Then, could you please tell me if my intuition on how to use the dominated convergence theorem is correct? $E\biggr[\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n\mathbf1_{(N=n)}\biggl] $ = $lim_{n \to \infty }E\biggr[\sum_{k=0}^n S_k\mathbf1_{(N=k)}\biggl] $ = $lim_{n \to \infty }E[X_n]$  and here I can apply the dom. theorem because $X_n \le nE(X_n)$  but I'm not sure of this last passage. Which is the r.v. Y that dominate Xn, all n?

Comment: I edited my answer so it answers your questions.

Comment: Infinitely grateful. Totally right.